# Nested Tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, nested

We have a table containing a couple of nested tables.  And, although we can query from the "flat" portion of the table from over a db link, we cannot seem to get it to query from the nested tables from over the db link.

I cannot seem to find any pages giving examples on how to access nested table content over a DB Link.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So you can query it ok when connected inside your database with the nested table, but are unable to query it through a database link? The basic syntax for querying can be found at: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3788331/So-what-is-an-Oracle-Nested-Table.htm

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting this error?

```
ORA-22804: remote operations not permitted on object tables or user-defined type columns
```

That's an annoying problem.  The only workaround I am aware of is to create the object name in both databases with the same `OID`.  Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myschema.my_type_name
    OID '4DEB8B43CCCA4FD9E05400144FFAE657' 
    IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(80);  -- or whatever your nested table is.
```

I've also seen that not work -- complaining about requiring global names to be in use.  But I've also seen it work in environments not using global names.  I'm not sure what that's about.